How to bulk load ~1M of JSON files into Redis?
Here is my current code in bash (based on https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/use/patterns/bulk-loading):
head=$(redis-cli -h $redis_server get .git-head)
if [[ ! $head ]]; then
    redis-cli -h $redis_server flushdb
    for fileOrFolder in $(ls -1); do
        time {
            find $fileOrFolder -type f |
                LC_ALL=C xargs -n1 bash -c 'echo -e *3\\r\\n\$3\\r\\nSET\\r\\n\$${#0}\\r\\n$0\\r\\n\$$(stat -c%s $0)\\r && cat $0 && echo -e \\r' |
                redis-cli -h $redis_server --pipe
        }
    done
    redis-cli -h $redis_server set .git-head $(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi

And it works, but there is a problem - the values are of the type string, not JSON. At least this is what Redis Insights tells me.
My question is - how can I modify the code to make sure the stored values are of the JSON type and keep the bulk load performance? Or even - should I modify it at all? Maybe the string type is good enough and would not limit our query abilities.
EDIT 1
To emphasize - the files are all JSON files already. To store them as JSON would mean to store them exactly as they are, only indicate to Redis that the values are valid JSONs.

If you don't need to perform complex queries on the data itself, then using strings is fine.
If you still want to store in JSON type, you can use JSON.SET command instead of SET
You can modify your code as below:
time {
        find $fileOrFolder -type f |
            LC_ALL=C xargs -n1 bash -c 'file_content=$(cat $0 | jq -Rs .); \
            file_size=$(stat -c%s $0); \
            redis-cli -h $redis_server json.set $0 . "{\"file\":\"$0\",\"size\":\"$file_size\",\"content\":$file_content}"' 
    }


What if $file_content has quotes or other non escaped characters?

The files are already valid JSON. But you are eliminating the bulk load feature completely here. Let me emphasize in the question that I still want to have the bulk load performance.

@mark I forgot that. And i think the use of jq tool is enough to handle quotes or other non escaped characters.

Note that there is no "bulk load" for the JSON data structure. Redis will need to phase your input and construct an internal tree representation. JSONs are not stored internally as strings. If you don't plan to use JSON.XXX commands nor index and search JSONs with FT.XXX commands - you should better use strings.

So it does not make sense to pipe JSON.SET commands similarly to the SET command, because redis --pipe would not behave as efficiently in that case? I thought redis --pipe is going to spare the 1M individual round trips.
